# when to say that the given information is (intersection) not (conditional probability)?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

There are two urns containing colored balls. The first urn contains 50 red balls and 50 blue
balls. The second urn contains 30 red balls and 70 blue balls. One of the two urns is
randomly chosen (both urns have probability 50% of being chosen) and then a ball is drawn
at random from one of the two urns. If a red ball is drawn, what is the probability that it
comes from the first urn?

my question is:

so here (1/2) is the red intersection first urn 
or it`s the p(red|first urn)
I need explanation for that point please 
and if the second one is the right 
why it   p(red|first urn) and not p(first urn| red)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

If we define the following events:

$U1$: Urn $1$ is chosen

$U2$: Urn $2$ is chosen

$R$: a red ball is chosen

then we have:

$P(U1)=P(U2)=P(R|U1)=50$%

The $50$% is *not* $P(U1 \cap R)$, for we have $P(U1 \cap R) = P(R|U1) \cdot P(U1) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}=0.25$

That is, $P(U1 \cap R)$ is the probability that you choose urn $1$ *and* pick a red ball, so that mreans you first need to pick urn $1$ ($50$% chance of that), and *then* you *also* need to pick a red ball, *given* that you picked urn $1$, and that is also $50$%, so for both to happen it's $50$% times $50$% is $25$%

Finally, you are asked to find $P(U1|R)$, and for that use Bayes' Law

Comment: but you figured that out from the syntax of the problem about the 50% being intersection  or conditional probability

Comment: @AhmedAraby The problem says that urn 1 contains $50$ red balls and $50$ blue balls, and so from that we can say that $P(R|U1) = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: okay , but when we can say that is probability of R intersection U1 what is the change that will happen to the problem syntax here in order to say that is an intersection

Comment: @AhmedAraby $P(R \cap U1)$ is the probability of picking urn 1 *and* getting a red ball. Or, in short: the probability of picking a red ball from urn $1$, *given* that you have not yet decided from which urn you're going to pick a ball.

Answer (score 1):

You have two urns with known amounts of red and blue balls.   This tells you the (conditional) probabilities for drawing a red ball from each *given* urn.

$$\mathsf P(R\mid U_1) = 50/100 = 5/10\\ \mathsf P(R\mid U_2)=30/100=3/10$$

You are to randomly select an urn (ie: without bias).   This tells you the (marginal) probabilities for selecting each urn. $$\mathsf P(U_1)=1/2\\ \mathsf P(U_2)=1/2$$

So then the probabilities for selecting each urn **and** drawing a red ball, will be the products.$$\mathsf P(U_1\cap R)= \mathsf P(U_1)~\mathsf P(R\mid U_1)= 5/20\\\mathsf P(U_2\cap R)=\mathsf P(U_2)~\mathsf P(R\mid U_2)=3/20$$

The Law of Total Probability tells us the (marginal) probability for drawing a red ball.$$\mathsf P(R)~{=\mathsf P(U_1\cap R)+\mathsf P(U_2\cap R)\\=\mathsf P(U_1)~\mathsf P(R\mid U_1)+\mathsf P(U_2)~\mathsf P(R\mid U_2)\\=8/20}$$

Now then, you are to evaluate the probability that urn 1 was selected *given* that a red ball was drawn.   From this we use wither the defiition for conditional probability, or Bayes' Rule.$$\begin{split}\mathsf P(U_1\mid R) &= \dfrac{\mathsf P(U_1\cap R)}{\mathsf P(R)} &\quad&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(U_1)~\mathsf P(R\mid U_1)}{\mathsf P(U_1)~\mathsf P(R\mid U_1)+\mathsf P(U_2)~\mathsf P(R\mid U_2)}\\ &=\dfrac{5}{8} \end{split}$$

---

Note: This should be anticipated, because 50 from the 80 red balls are in urn 1 *and* both urns contain an equal total count for balls.